# Why the space of Katětov functions with finite support is separable?

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry, separable-spaces, polish-spaces

Let $(X, \rho)$ be a metric space. A function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is called Katětov map if
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le \rho(x, y) \le f(x) + f(y) \quad \forall x, y \in X.$$
Denote the space of all Katětov maps on $X$ by $E(X)$. This is a metric space with sup-metric.

For $Y \subset X, f \in E(Y)$ let $\hat f(x) := \sup\limits_{y \in Y} \left(f(y)+\rho(x, y)\right)$; the map $\hat f$ is called the Katětov extension of $f$. We say that $S \subset X$ is a support of $f \in E(X)$ if $f$ is a Katětov extension of $f|_S$. Consider $E(X, \omega) = \{f \in E(X): f \text{ has a finite support}\}$. A Kuratowski map $x \mapsto \rho(\cdot, x)$ embeds $X$ isometrically into $E(X, \omega)$.

I want to know, why if $X$ is separable then $E(X, \omega)$ is separable too. This fact is used in a construction of Urysohn space. I would be very much appreciated if someone could provide me with any hints, proofs or references.

Comment: If $X$ is the real line then $f(x)=|x|$ is an ubnounded function satisfying these inequalities. So supremum metric cannot be used on this space.

Comment: When you say that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq f(x)+f(y)$, are you implicitely assuming that $f(x)+f(y)\geq 0$, Ie,  $f:X\to\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: @UserA $f(x) + f(x) \ge \rho(x, x) = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) \ge 0$ so a Katětov map is automatically non-negative.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, if $X = \mathbb R$ then $f(x) = |x|$ is indeed a Katětov map because $f(x) = \rho(x, 0)$ and every map of the form $\rho(\cdot, x_0)$ is a Katětov map. However, we don't need the condition $\rho(0, |x|) < \infty$ because $g(x) \equiv 0$ is not a Katětov map. Sup-metric is well-defined because one could easily check that if $f, g \in E(X)$ and $x_0 \in X$ is some fixed point then $|f(x) - g(x)| \le f(x_0) + g(x_0)$ for every $x \in X$. Maybe you got me wrong: by sup-metric I mean that $\rho(f, g) = \sup_x |f(x) - g(x)|$ for $f, g \in E(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think there is a typo in your definition of a Katětov extension: given $Y \subseteq X$ and $f \in E(Y)$, the Katětov extension of $f$ is given by $\hat{f}(x) = \inf_{y \in Y} f(y) + \rho(x,y)$.

Now suppose $X$ is separable, and let's show that $E(X, \omega)$ is separable. Since $X$ is separable, it has a countable dense subset $D$.  We prove the separability in $E(X, \omega)$ in two steps.

> **Step 1.** $E(D, \omega)$ is separable.

Let $S \subseteq D$ be a finite subset.  Consider the subspace $E(D, S) := \{f \in E(D, \omega) \mid \operatorname{supp}(f) = S\}$.  Each $f$ in this subspace is determined by its values on $S$, so the subspace can be identified with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^S$.  Since the finite-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^S$ is separable and subsets of separable spaces are separable, we see that $E(D, S)$ is separable too.

Now, note that $E(D, \omega) = \bigcup_{S \subseteq D \text{ finite}} E(D, S)$.  This is a countable union since there are countably finite subsets in a countable set.  Since a countable union of separable spaces is separable, this proves that $E(D, \omega)$ is separable, as claimed.

> **Step 2.** $E(D, \omega)$ is dense in $E(X, \omega)$.

Let $f \in E(X, \omega)$, with finite support $S$.  Fix $\epsilon > 0$.  For each $s \in S$, choose $x_s \in D$ such that $d(x_s, s) < \epsilon$ using the denseness of $D$ in $X$.  We define $g \in E(D, \omega)$ to be the Katětov extension of $f|_{\{x_s\}_{s \in S}}$.  Write $\hat{g}$ for the image of $g$ under the extension map $E(D, \omega) \to E(X, \omega)$.

We compute.  For all $s \in S$, we have
$$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}
\begin{align*}
\abs{f(s) - \hat{g}(s)} &\leq \abs{f(s) - f(x_s)} + \abs{f(x_s) - \hat{g}(x_s)} + \abs{\hat{g}(x_s) - \hat{g}(s)} \\
&< \epsilon + 0 + \epsilon \\
&= 2\epsilon
\end{align*}
$$
since $f$ and $\hat{g}$ are Katětov maps and hence $1$-Lipschitz.

Now, on the one hand, for any $x \in X$,
$$\begin{align*}
\hat{g}(x) &= \min_{s \in S} g(x_s) + \rho(x, x_s) \\
&= \min_{s \in S} f(x_s) + \rho(x, x_s) \\
&\geq \min_{s \in S} f(x) \\
&= f(x).
\end{align*}$$

On the other hand,
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \min_{s \in S} f(s) + \rho(x, s) \\
&> \min_{s \in S} \hat{g}(s) - 2\epsilon + \rho(x, s) \\
&\geq \min_{s \in S} \hat{g}(x) - 2\epsilon \\
&= \hat{g}(x) - 2\epsilon.
\end{align*}$$

In summary, given any $f \in E(X, \omega)$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $g \in E(D, \omega)$ such that $\left\lVert f - \hat{g} \right\rVert = \sup_{x \in X} \abs{f(x) - \hat{g}(x)} < 2\epsilon$.  In other words, $E(D, \omega)$ is dense in $E(X, \omega)$.

Finally, since denseness is a transitive relation on subspaces, combining the two steps above shows that $E(X, \omega)$ is separable, as desired.